# Removing duplicate words using sed

Tags: regex, sed

Ive been looking for code that helps me to get my desired output. Input file contains upto max 8 columns and minimum of 4 columns. After researching i found that it falls in the category of grouping/back-reference. I tried to use sed but of no avail. Data contains 8 to 15 digit numbers, IP addresses and alphabetical word. From $2 onwards, there is a repetion in the string of the $2 and it is for maximum 5 times. format shown below;

Input file:

```
410011515534576 923000720575 10.225.4.236 CokeVPN
410011515534579 923000720578 923000720578 923000720578 10.225.4.239 CokeVPN
410018137112489 923054440014 923054440014 923054440014 923054440014 10.225.1.212 CokeVPN
```

Desired output:

```
410011515534576 923000720575 10.225.4.236 CokeVPN
410011515534579 923000720578 10.225.4.239 CokeVPN
410018137112489 923054440014 10.225.1.212 CokeVPN
```

I am looking to remove these repeating entries in columns. Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the first column and the last three, you can use the following `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '{$2=$(NF-2); $3=$(NF-1); $4=$NF; NF=4}1' file
```

It returns:

```
410011515534576 923000720575 10.225.4.236 CokeVPN
410011515534579 923000720578 10.225.4.239 CokeVPN
410018137112489 923054440014 10.225.1.212 CokeVPN
```

It resets the line by setting the 2nd parameter as the pe-penultimate, 3rd as penultimate and 4th and last as the last one. Then `1` triggers the default action for `awk`: `{print $0}`.

---

To be sure you don't screw other lines, you can add a condition: do this just if the number of fields is bigger or equal to 4:

```
awk 'NF>=4{$2=$(NF-2); $3=$(NF-1); $4=$NF; NF=4}1' file
```

Comment: Hello fedorqui, it is returning me below fatal error.
awk: (FILENAME=coke.out FNR=1) fatal: attempt to access field -2

Comment: This is because you are working with input files that differ from what you have shown in the question. This needs to have at least 4 fields in each line. If you provide a more representative file I can rethink it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Few entries are of only first 2 strings. 
for example;
410011515534576 923000720575

Comment: @TaqdeesPervaiz then you can do `awk 'NF>=4{$2=$(NF-2); $3=$(NF-1); $4=$NF; NF=4}1' file`.

Comment: Thankyou so much fedorqui

Comment: So what's happening with accepting and unaccepting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed command that use the backreference to the group 2 to replace possible repeatitions:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]* \)\([^ ]*\)\( \2\)* /\1\2 /' file
```